# General Infinitive vs Gerund usage

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, infinitive-vs-gerund

Is there a general rule telling me when I should use an Infinitive or a Gerund?
For example, why is in this sentence a Gerund instead of an Infinitive?

> "The aim of this report is to **give** suggestions to a group of elderly tourists on how to **make** the most of their morning in Roxburgh".

How do I decide whether I use each of them?

Comment: The noun "aim" only licenses (specifically permits) _to_-infinitival complements, not gerund-participial ones, as predicative complement. There's no simple rule that you can follow -- you just have to familiarise yourself with which heads license which complements.

Comment: What gerund? **To give** is an infinitive. **To make** is an infinitive.

Comment: @JeffMorrow *Giving*, of course. They're presumably asking why they can't say *The aim of this report is **giving** suggestions...*

Comment: The aim goes to purpose, so "to" is best. Anyway, you cannot use a gerund here (giving).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the use of gerunds and to-infinitives, there isn't one simple rule, unfortunately. More often than not, you have to remember patterns. Let's take the noun "**aim**" as an example:

- Aim + of + to-inf: *The aim **of** the project is **to** help the homeless.* (this explains the use of "to give" in your sentence)
- with the aim + of: We visit schools **with** the aim **of** getting kids interested in the issue.

"**How to** do something" also must be memorized. As a rule, "to" is followed by infinities but not always (e.g.I'm looking forward to *hearing* from you):

- Will you tell me **how to do** it?

Answering you question "How do I decide whether I use each of them?", I'd say use a dictionary when in doubt. It usually gives all the information on patterns. For example, the Collins Dictionary does it like this:

[image]

Take note of what is given in the brackets.